# AVB Streaming Stored file from sever to client : TimeStamping issue

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am working on AVB application.As we have created gstreamer plugins at talker side and listener side and we used that plugins to transfer stored media.

I am using below pipeline

Talker side :

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/input.mp4 ! queue ! avbsink interface=eth0 fd=0 (here avbsink is created property to transfer avb packets)

Listener side :

gst-launch-1.0 avbsrc interface=eth0 dataSync=1 mediaType=0 fd=0 ! queue ! qtdemux name=mux mux.video_0 ! queue ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink mux.audio_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
(i tried vaapidecode and vaapisink instead of avdec_h264 and autovideosink for hardware accelerator )

Error comming on listener side is

"WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapisink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.

Additional debug info:

gstbasesink.c(2683) : gst_base_sink_is_too_late(): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiSink:vaapisink0;

There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow. "

I have seen one solution to use sync=false then i have added sync=false with vaapisink and error message got eliminate  but still video is not playing smoothly. its continuously gating stop and again starting.

Is there any solution to play video continuously.( Only high quality video(720p or more) is not playing, application is working for low quality video ).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the size of the buffer is not enough since a frame of hd video has more pixels. The other point I can propose is may be you can apply some sort of compression algorithm prior to sending the frame to listener but I am not sure if compression is contradicting any one of AVB protocols.